# SWT - Creating a grid of numbers that I'd like to be able to tab through with keyboard

Tags: java, swt

This problem has been driving me CRAZY!!! Using SWT, I'd like to create a grid of numbers that I can tab traverse using the keyboard. I'd like to be able to select and click into each cell (not just on the numbers) to perform some action. In other words, I'm looking for a way to make a true FLAT button. The goal here is to make the grid accessible with screen readers such that when a cell has focus, the screen reader will read the number value in the middle of each cell.

Originally, I created a GridLayout with a set of button controls to display the number values. This actually worked but I didn't want the buttons to look like buttons. The SWT.FLAT style for button controls doesn't work on Windows operating systems. This is caused by an OS limitation.

Next I then tried converting all buttons to labels but since label controls cant take focus, I couldn't implement any type of tab traversal. Next I tried replacing all labels with read-only text controls. I was able to re-introduce the tab traversal/focusing but I can't get the text to display in the dead-center of each cell. This is actually caused by a SWT limitation. The SWT.CENTER style for text controls only affects the horizontal alignment. Text controls can't be vertically aligned.

So finally, someone told me to wrap each read-only text control in a Composite. This allowed me to center the read-only text controls but I don't know how to make the composite itself to be tab traversed.

Any ideas on how I can get this done or how I can make controls that typically dont take focus (like composite, canvas, label) actually take focus so I can tab traverse each control with my keyboard?

I'm fairly new to java and SWT so I apologize if some of this is confusing. Many thanks. This is how I've constructed each of my cells thus far (I've replaced the read-only text with CLabel controls):

```
Display display = new Display();
Shell shell = new Shell(display); 

GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(5, false);
gridLayout.marginWidth = 0;
gridLayout.marginHeight = 0;
gridLayout.horizontalSpacing = 1;
gridLayout.verticalSpacing = 1;
shell.setLayout(gridLayout);    

Composite resetComp = new Composite(shell, SWT.BORDER);
GridData compgridData = new GridData(SWT.CENTER, SWT.CENTER, true, true);
GridData resetGD = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, false, false);
resetGD.verticalSpan = 2;    
resetComp.setLayoutData(resetGD);
resetComp.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, false));  

CLabel resetCLabel = new CLabel(resetComp, SWT.SHADOW_OUT | SWT.CENTER);
resetCLabel.setText("Reset"); //$NON-NLS-1$
resetCLabel.setLayoutData(compgridData);
resetCLabel.setBackground(Display.getCurrent().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_RED)); //$NON-NLS-1$

resetComp.setToolTipText(resetCLabel.getText());
```

Comment: What does "focus" mean on a composite?  Are you going to paint it differently or something?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a trick, maybe it will suits you: create each button inside a Composite, and set the size of the Button bigger than its parent Composite; This way, the border of button is not visible, because outside of its parent composite.

```
private static final int GRID_SIZE = 5;
private static final int CELL_SIZE = 40;
private static final int PADDING = 3;

public static void main (String [] args) {
    Display display = new Display ();
    Shell shell = new Shell (display);
    shell.setLayout(new GridLayout(GRID_SIZE, true));

    for (int i = 0; i < GRID_SIZE * GRID_SIZE; i++) {
        createButton(shell, i+1);     
    }

    shell.pack ();
    shell.open ();
    while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
        if (!display.readAndDispatch ()) display.sleep ();
    }
    display.dispose ();
}

private static void createButton(Shell shell, final int number) {
    Composite c = new Composite(shell, SWT.NONE);
    c.setLayoutData(new GridData(CELL_SIZE, CELL_SIZE));

    Button button = new Button(c, SWT.NONE);
    button.setText(Integer.toString(number));
    button.setBounds(-PADDING, -PADDING, CELL_SIZE + 2 * PADDING, CELL_SIZE + 2 * PADDING);

    button.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
        public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
            System.err.println("click on " + number);
        }
    });
}
```

It fulfills your requirement: focus, centered. The result may be more or less nice depending on the Windows version (try to change the padding, or add a border to the Composite, it may look nicer).

Comment: Wow.  That's bizarrely clever.